# Mac Port install arguments

Tags: install, macports, python

I need to install [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch) on my mac. Since I prefer Python for Scientific Computing I though that it would install PyROOT by default. That didn't happen. After I looked on [PyROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/pyroot) site i found that installation is done by that line:

```
./configure <arch> --enable-python [--with-python-incdir=<dir>] [--with-python-libdir=<dir>]
gmake
```

What would be alternative for that line above for enabling python on my macports installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinstall root from macports and tell it what variants (i.e. additions it needs)

`port info root` lists the variants e.g.

> avahi, clang31, clang32, clang33, cocoa, debug, fftw3, fitsio, gcc43, gcc44, gcc45, gcc46, gcc47, [+]gcc48,
>                         gcc49, [+]graphviz, [+]gsl, ldap, mariadb, [+]minuit2, mysql, mysql51, mysql55, odbc, [+]opengl, percona,
>                         postgresql90, postgresql92, pythia, python26, python27, python31, python32, python33, python34, qt_mac,
>                         [+]roofit, ruby, [+]soversion, sqlite3, [+]ssl, [+]tmva, [+]xml, xrootd

The ones with [+] are installed by default.

So in your case choose the python version you want (e.g. python 3.3 as latest released one), also anything else you need as they are done all at the same time, so I might add qt_mac and sqlite3 as well

```
sudo port install root +python33 +sqlite3 +qt_mac
```

Note that python executable will be /opt/local/bin/python3.3 but you can use the select port to make it the one that /opt/local/bin/python uses

Comment: Just a report, everything works all right. Thanks!